# Chromecast RemoteMediaClient sometimes doesnt work for certain actions like "play" and "pause"

Tags: android, chromecast

I have setup the new chromecast sdk v3 and i cant figure out this issue.

If user click one of the videos in MainActivity , it goes to VideoActivity.

And I setup the menu item using CastButtonFactory for both Activities

```
castMenuItem = CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(), menu,
                R.id.action_mediaroute);
```

but i just add the sessionlistener in VideoActivity

```
 mCastContext.getSessionManager().addSessionManagerListener(mSessionManagerListener, CastSession.class);
```

The issue is , if i connect to cast device using the castmenu item in VideoActivity , i can always control the playback using API

```
remoteMediaClient.pause();
remoteMediaClient.play();
```

and the MediaRouteButtonDialog (the one will popup if you click the cast menu item in a connected mode) playback control also work in this case.

However, if i connect to cast device, starting the session using the cast menu item in MainActivity, the APIs doesnt work and neither does the MediaRouteButtonDialog.

**works:**

```
remoteMediaClient.load();
```

**doesnt work :**

```
remoteMediaClient.play();
remoteMediaClient.pause();
```

Comment: do you still experiencing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to extend [MediaIntentReceiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/MediaIntentReceiver). It can be subclassed to handle custom actions or override the default behaviours when handling pre-defined actions.

If you have implemented your own MediaIntentReceiver, you need to add it to the manifest, and also set its name in the CastMediaOptions.

By default the fragment shows a play/pause toggle button. Developers can use the attribute [castControlButtons](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_advanced#choose-mini-controller-buttons) to override which buttons to show. The supported control buttons are defined as ID resources.

Here is an example that places a play/pause toggle button:

```
item>
    <item>@id/cast_button_type_play_pause_toggle</item>
    ...
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/cast_mini_controller"
        ...
        app:castControlButtons="cast_mini_controller_control_buttons"
        class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment">
```